# How get session in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session

I wanna ask you about to get session in html,.. i want to add url and get session when i click the button.

I have viewer page, after i click the button "go_to1.png" it go to page1.html

```
<html>
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/folder/file.js"></script
</html>
    <div id="topMenu">
        <div id="left-bar">
            <a href="page1.html"><img src="image/go_to1.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="center-inside-bar">
            <img class="logo" src="image/img.png">
        </div>
        <div id="right-bar">
        <button class="read" tabindex="-1"></button>
            <a href="page2.html"><img src="image/go_to2.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

in page1.html it show the link that i want show.

```
</div>
<iframe src="http://url/" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto">
    <p>Your browser doesn't support iframe</p>
</iframe>
```

where should i put the session code and how to do it.

-newbie-

Comment: do you want to read any session variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "Session"?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? link to page_1.html should work as you have it

Comment: i mean, after i login it go to viewer page, and then there's a button.  after i click the button, i want use session. to get login session. @Mathew

Comment: why do you need session ??

Comment: i need it because, i have login page, after login i want goto other page. so i want to use login session. @rai.skumar

Answer (score 1):

You can't html doesn't allow session. You have to use any server side coding i.e php/coldfusion/asp.net. If you want to send only a unique value for that page you can create with js and append it on the url before sending. You can create random string with js with this single line of code.

```
var rndId = randomString(8);
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer ? Whatever you have written.

Comment: actually i'm using node.js.. i guess is possible to do it..is it right? @souvicksce